# Monitor Twitter for multiple words / hashtags?

Tags: jquery, twitter, twitter-search

I'm currently using a script on my page to retrieve each time a new item on Twitter with a certain word. The script uses the URL http://twitter.com/#!/search?q=mySearchWord.
The script is inspired by **elektronaut**.
I would like to "upgrade" my script to monitor several words or hashtags, so for example it monitors: food, fruit, fish, meat, bread, cake.

I’ve been browsing around Google but can’t find any script that does that so I think it might not be possible.

Does anyone have knowledge of a JavaScript that does that or a solution to my existing script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can separate alternative keywords with `OR`:

```
http://twitter.com/#!/search?q=food+OR+fruit+OR+fish+OR+etc
```

(source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search)

Comment: Beaten, too bad the "1 answer already posted" didn't get to me in time.